# JSX Component Lint warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React and trying to get my head around it. Working on some basic form field validation using guide here:

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/

I have this working, but i need to change the format of the renderField component.

This works fine:

```
renderField = (
        {
            input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
        },
    ) => (
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
        </div>
        );
```

but i need to remove the enclosing < d i v > from this, to make the following:

```
renderField = (
        {
            input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
        },
    ) => ( 
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}    
        );
```

When doing this, the linter is going crazy regarding the second line here. It is expecting a ) after the input tag and has complaints about pretty much every character on the second line!

I'm sure this is a pretty simple concept that i am not grasping, so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't remove the div because elements of a component should all be under on tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that situation you can replace by:

Using this `<></>`

```
renderField = (
        {
            input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
        },
    ) => ( 
           <>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}    
           </>
        );
```

or

```
import react, {Fragment} from 'react';

    renderField = (
            {
                input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
            },
        ) => ( 
               <Fragment>
                <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
                {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}    
               </Fragment>
            );
```

This will avoid rendering a parent `div` or any not desired HTML element for enclosing your JSX.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wrap your elements in `div` then you can use [`Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html),

```
 renderField = (
        {
            input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
        },
    ) => (
         <React.Fragment> 
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}    
         </React.Fragment>
        );
```

Or the **short syntax** is **empty tag**,

```
 renderField = (
        {
            input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning },
        },
    ) => (
         <> 
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}    
         </>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is related to JSX, you have to return one root at the end, so in above case you are returning multiple DOM elements at the end so that's why its not working.

[read this](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html) for more information.

And if you do not want any span or div to enclose your elements then you can use `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` to enclose your elements if you're using React 16 or above.

Comment: thanks for the detailed info, will check that link out!